# Scope of document elements created in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and web development in general, and I'm trying to write a renderer that can draw each slice in a CT scan as a 2D image.

I have a long thin (512x49664) image made from 512x97 slices, each of which is just a 512x512 image. I've already ascertained that this will upset webgl, so I was planning to grab individual slices from the image by drawing it on a canvas and copying the image data into a texture.

My question is: if I have a function in which I do something like:

```
// Create a small canvas to contain a single slice.
function getSlice(sliceNumber){
    var sliceCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    sliceCanvas.width = 512;
    sliceCanvas.height = 512;
    var sliceContext = sliceCanvas.getContext('2d');
    sliceContext.drawImage(image, 0, 512*sliceNumber, 512, 512, 0, 0, 512, 512);
}
```

What happens to the canvas I created when the function exits?

Comment: you create your canvas element in getSlice(). so it will not be available/disposed after the function got executed.

Comment: [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) covers memory mangement quite well

Comment: FYI you've created an element but you've not put it in the DOM so it will not be rendered

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been:

- Added to the DOM
- Stored in a variable or property that is still in scope
- Returned anywhere

… there are no references remaining to it, so it will be marked for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a *DOM* element via *javascript* DOM API, you should attach this element to the page *document*.

Otherwise this element will never shown in your page.

So you have to add a line like this in your code:

```
document.body.appendChild(sliceCanvas);
```

If you call your function multiple times, you should check the *canvas* creation:

```
var sliceCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
```

or

```
var sliceCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvasId');
```

Then check:

```
if (!sliceCanvas) {
    sliceCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    sliceCanvas.id = 'myCanvasId'; // optional
    document.body.appendChild(sliceCanvas);
}

// here your code...
```

**UPDATE:**

Consider to change the `document.body` with the proper DOM element where you want to place your canvas.